# H13 desc="Connection closed without response" Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I have this small little weather app that works just fine locally but I can't figure out how to deploy it on Heroku, it always crashes with H13 error.

**Here's the logs:**

```
2021-04-06T19:47:08.155540+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-refuge-08385.herokuapp.com request_id=c475a57b-ed20-4427-90e0-419cc9b89376 fwd="181.167.200.240" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=242ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

**But I also get some stuff like:**

```
2021-04-06T20:01:30.566033+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on port: 3000
2021-04-06T20:01:31.466908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-06T20:03:00.358781+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app.js:36
2021-04-06T20:03:00.358799+00:00 app[web.1]: const cityWeather = weatherData.weather[0].main;
2021-04-06T20:03:00.358800+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-04-06T20:03:00.358800+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-06T20:03:00.358801+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I imagine it cannot read cityWeather because the app somehow crashed, it works just fine locally.

**This is my app.js:**

```
// npm modules
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const https = require('https');

require('dotenv').config();

// initializing express
const app = express();

// setting up ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// express config
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

// home
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // query information
  const baseURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?';
  const cityQuery = 'Buenos Aires';
  const units = 'metric';
  const appID = process.env.WEATHER_API;
  const url = `${baseURL}appid=${appID}&q=${cityQuery}&units=${units}`;

  // icon information
  const iconURL = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/';
  const iconSize = '@2x.png';

  https.get(url, (response) => {
    response.on('data', (data) => {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      const selectedCity = weatherData.name;
      const cityWeather = weatherData.weather[0].main;
      const minTemp = weatherData.main.temp_min;
      const maxTemp = weatherData.main.temp_max;
      const weatherPressure = weatherData.main.pressure;
      const weatherHumidity = weatherData.main.humidity;
      const windSpeed = weatherData.wind.speed;
      const weatherTemp = weatherData.main.temp;
      const feelsLike = weatherData.main.feels_like;
      const weatherIcon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
      const showIcon = `${iconURL}${weatherIcon}${iconSize}`;
      const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;

      res.render('home', {
        selectedCity,
        cityWeather,
        minTemp,
        maxTemp,
        weatherPressure,
        weatherHumidity,
        windSpeed,
        showIcon,
        weatherDescription,
        weatherTemp,
        feelsLike,
      });
    });
  });
});

// response to client city query
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // query information
  const baseURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?';
  const cityQuery = req.body.cityName;
  const units = 'metric';
  const appID = process.env.WEATHER_API;
  const url = `${baseURL}appid=${appID}&q=${cityQuery}&units=${units}`;

  // icon information
  const iconURL = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/';
  const iconSize = '@2x.png';

  https.get(url, (response) => {
    response.on('data', (data) => {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      const selectedCity = weatherData.name;
      const cityWeather = weatherData.weather[0].main;
      const minTemp = weatherData.main.temp_min;
      const maxTemp = weatherData.main.temp_max;
      const weatherPressure = weatherData.main.pressure;
      const weatherHumidity = weatherData.main.humidity;
      const windSpeed = weatherData.wind.speed;
      const weatherTemp = weatherData.main.temp;
      const feelsLike = weatherData.main.feels_like;
      const weatherIcon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
      const showIcon = `${iconURL}${weatherIcon}${iconSize}`;
      const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;

      res.render('city', {
        selectedCity,
        cityWeather,
        minTemp,
        maxTemp,
        weatherPressure,
        weatherHumidity,
        windSpeed,
        showIcon,
        weatherDescription,
        weatherTemp,
        feelsLike,
      });
    });
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port: 3000');
});
```

Can anyone help me a bit to solve this? I tried many things but nothing worked and I don't know what else to try. Thanks